# Auto filter for text box with coma separated string

Tags: c#

As per requirement we need to apply auto filter option  for an email text box for a windows application.
We are able to implement  the auto filter for email text box using “AutoCompleteCustomSource”

For that , we have programmatically created “AutoCompleteStringCollection”  list and set it to the “AutoCompleteCustomSource” property of the textbox.
Our email textbox also having the option  enter multiple emails using a coma separator.

In the case of multiple emails the auto filter not working properly.

For example , if we enter “Sa” , it will show the emails starting with “Sa”
But if we enter  “Sa” after entering an email (“rahul@gmail.com,Sa”) ,it is not showing any items starting with “Sa”.

Is there any way to solve this issue? It would be grateful, if you can provide a solution.

```
 AutoCompleteStringCollection data = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        data.Add("Mahesh Chand");
        data.Add("Mac Jocky");
        data.Add("Millan Peter");
        textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = data;
```

Best Regards,

Comment: what have you done so far? can you show the code? we can provide help but not generate code from scratch

Comment: I just added code. I used name instead of email id

Comment: Unfortunately this is not really possible. The problem is that you provide a (maybe virtual) list of possible values that can be entered and auto-completed. But how this list is used will be decided by the textbox itself and not be the source.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Just use a separate textbox for each address.

Answer (score -1):

As a starter you could basically extend your `AutoCompleteStringCollection data` with the already written string if you encounter a `,`.

This here makes the first step. I took the `TextChanged` event to check for the `,`. and then put the already written text in front of each entry.

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text.Last() == ',')
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            data[i] = textBox2.Text + data[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Disclaimer: Problems still to be solved:

- avoid to show the already written name
- handle the case that the user removes the `,` because up to now the extension remains
- return to the start state of your `AutoCompleteStringCollection`

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. We cannot append the already written name, since there is possibility to insert the name in between two names.

Comment: @Ranish then you are up to almost write your own autocomplete with much more code I guess. Good luck

Comment: @Ranish maybe you should include this requirement into your post

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include it in my requirement.  I am able to achieve the auto filter using custom own control . Thanks for the support.

Comment: No problem, if you have a working solution you could post it here as an answer so that you can nail this post.